# List is empty even though I have successfully added items in the for loop

Tags: kotlin, closures

My list is empty even though I added items to it in the for loop of my closure. It seems like that it is not working because of the closure but I have no clue how to fix it. Logging in the for loop shows that data is being added.

```
    val crewList= mutableListOf<Crew>()


    myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for(child in dataSnapshot.children){
                val childCrew = child.getValue(Crew::class.java)
                childCrew?.let { crewList.add(it) }
                Log.i("crewList", crewList.toString())
                //crewList is not empty
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("Error", "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
        }
    })

    //crewList is empty
    Log.i("crewlist", crewList.toString())
    return crewList.toList()
```

Comment: Are you taking into account that the `toList()` call in the last line will create a new list object, initialised to yiur (presumably empty) `crewList` but separate from it?  Even if the listener gets called and `crewList` updated, that new list will remain empty.

Comment: ah good to know, I just wanted to convert my mutableList to a list.

Comment: `MutableList` is a subinterface of `List`, so you could probably drop the `toList()` call entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because addValueEventListener is async but your return is synchronized.

Your code reads:

1. Create a list
2. Add an event listener to myRef
3. Log and return the list created in step 1(empty)
4. The event listener triggered by hand or automatically, after the return and `Log.i` code.